# What does this term mean, and where in the code is the issue?

Tags: python-3.x

Im not quite sure how to fix this but I think it is related to the fact that str, and float are for 2 different things. Though I do not see where the issue is. This code is for identifying and generating URL's based on a shoe size and model number in the URL.
*I AM VERY NEW TO CODING*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm sure there's lots of us (like myself) that would like to help you answer your question, but it's pretty difficult to do without some examples. Please edit your post to include a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that I (or someone else) can better help you

Comment: Please explain further to help you put the part of your code

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to concatenate a string value (str) with a  float type numeric value.
In my opinion, you should transform your float into a string with str(number).